# While generating kernel image, Getting error as unrecognized command line option ‘-mlongcalls'

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, buildroot

While generating kernel image for Xtensa ISS platform
i'm getting compilation error as unrecognized command line option ‘-mlongcalls'
Can any one explain me about the -mlongcalls ? and Why it's unrecognized ?
I'm using Buildroot for generating cross compilation environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

refer to `man gcc`

"

```
**-mlongcalls**
**-mno-longcalls**

       When this option is enabled, GCC instructs the assembler to translate direct calls to indirect calls unless it can determine that the target of a direct call is in the range
       allowed by the call instruction.  This translation typically occurs for calls to functions in other source files.  Specifically, the assembler translates a direct "CALL"
       instruction into an "L32R" followed by a "CALLX" instruction.  The default is -mno-longcalls.  This option should be used in programs where the call target can potentially be
       out of range.  This option is implemented in the assembler, not the compiler, so the assembly code generated by GCC still shows direct call instructions---look at the
       disassembled object code to see the actual instructions.  Note that the assembler uses an indirect call for every cross-file call, not just those that really are out of range.
```

"

Comment: Why its unrecognized ? (mine is 4.7 gcc compiler)